# How do I center these buttons in my div with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I center buttons in my div at png?

[image: words.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just assigned its container `text-align: center;`

```css
div{
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>aaa</button>
  <button>aaa</button>
  <button>aaa</button>
  <button>aaa</button>
</div>
```